# В чем разница между ping и heartbeat в TCP?

Tags: сокет, tcp-ip

В моем представлении проверка наличия соединения может делаться 2 способами:

1. Каждая из сторон по таймеру отправляет "пакет" send'ом. Но другая ничего не делает при его получении, тупо игнорирует. Однако если до первой стороны не доходит ответный ACK, то следующий вызов send уже выдавает ошибку на первой стороне - и она принимает меры. И та же логика симметрично с другой стороны.
2. Первая сторона отправляет "пакет" send'ом. Вторая тоже. Затем они ждут ответные "пакеты" друг друга и отправляют ответы на эти ответы, которые также принимают, после чего отправляют ответы уже на эти ответы и т.д.
   Этот вариант реализовывал я, когда только изучал надежность с TCP.

Итак, какой из них heartbeat, какой - ping?
Если здесь нет heartbeat'а или ping'а, то как тогда он выглядит?

И углубленный вопрос - чем является стандартный keep-alive - heartbeatом или pingом?

Comment: Вообще настоящий ping никакого отношения к TCP не имеет, он основан на протоколе ICMP, уровня IP. А так в принципе этим словом могут называть все что угодно, просто потому что похоже

Answer (score 3):

Для начала, наименования "keepalive", "heartbeat" и "ping" не являются официальной классификацией способов связи и разные люди могут использовать эти слова в разных смыслах.

Но, вообще-то, принципиально разных способов проверки связи - два.

Первый проверки связи - это когда одна из сторон (или обе) периодически посылает контрольные сообщения. В случае длительного отсутствия данных вторая сторона считает связь разорванной.

Второй способ проверки связи основан на периодических запросах и проверке ответов.

Достоинство первого способа проверки линии - меньше служебного трафика. Достоинство второго способа - возможность задания независимых настроек на разных концах линии (в первом способе настройки клиента и сервера обязаны быть согласованными).

---

Применительно к протоколу TCP. У этого протокола есть свой "официальный" способ проверки связи, который использует драйвер TCP если правильно настроить сокет. Этот способ - второго типа, т.е. пакеты посылает та сторона которую интересует состояние соединения. Однако, пакеты с запросом посылаются только при простое соединения; при работающем соединении нет смысла посылать лишние пакеты, и так очевидно что связь есть. Для проверки связи используются сегменты нулевого размера, в ответ на них ожидается пакет ACK.

Также поверх TCP можно реализовать любые другие способы проверки связи, но это уже будет проверка связи на прикладном уровне, а не на уровне TCP.

---

PS По поводу ваших способов. Первый способ повторяет логику TCP, но уже на прикладном уровне. Второй из ваших способов - это напрасная трата сетевых ресурсов, не делайте так.

Comment: Не сразу понял ,что "проверка ответов" - это проверка ACK'ов. Все-таки под ответом подразумевается прикладной уровень.

Comment: Второй из моих способов работал, когда у клиента был "отключен" интернет за неуплату. Подключения быстро рвались, но несколькими "пакетами" успевали перекинуться. А вот, к слову, TeamViewer - не мог к нему подключиться. Да, без лишнего трафика доходило бы еще больше "пакетов", но разница?

Comment: @koshkashoshka ответ - это не обязательно TCP ACK. Но может им быть.

Comment: Если там не только ACK, а и содержание буфера, которое нужно читать - то это примерно то же, что мой второй способ.

Comment: @koshkashoshka разница большая. Мобильные пользователи, к примеру, за такую "проверку связи" вас точно убьют. :-)

Comment: У кого-то до сих пор "лимитный" тариф? Кстати, считал. Точных значений не помню. Но невелики вроде бы.

Comment: @koshkashoshka проблема не в тарифе, а в батарее

Comment: проверю трафик своего самсунга как-нибудь. именно о заводских приложениях речь, да.